# Difference between T-SQL and MySQL's SELECT syntax

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql, select

So I wanted to make an online judge system on MySql, which will run on NodeJs and using ReactJs as frontend library.

In short term, Online judge system is used to grade and give feedback to uploaded script, depends on whether it returns an error, correct, time-out, or else. I designed this system to replace the old method of assignment correction which still manual.

The problem is, the old system is based on Sql server's TSQL, and I am not really sure whether TSQL is supported in NodeJS nor whether it actually had any difference with MySQL syntax, and actually didn't have a plan to use it at all as the base of my new system. (I planned to stick with MySQL as the base of the new online judge system)

What I wanted to ask is, is there any difference between T-SQL and MySQL SELECT syntax?

For example, I know that

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name>
```

return the same result in both TSQL and MySQL.
But what if there's more complex query that includes JOIN or ORDER/GROUP query.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Most of the differences will be in built in functions (for instance, t-sql `GetDate()` vs MySql `Now()`) etc`. One more difference is t-sql `Top` vs MySql `Limit`. If you have a specific statement you want to translate from one to the other, and having problems translating it, post it as a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js does support SQL Server e.g. [mssql package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql).

Both DBMS products support a common subset of ANSI/ISO standard SQL and have proprietary extensions as well. The effort to convert the app to MySQL will depend on what proprietary features are used as well as ANSI SQL constructs used that not yet implemented in MySQL.